# Spring RestController POST accepting a basic HTML form

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I'm attempting to post a simple HTML form to Spring RestController using @ModelAttribute and MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE as consumed data type. I've double checked all of my forms fields which match my request bean.

When the request enters the mapped method, all of the request beans fields are null.

```java
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebServiceController {

    @RequestMapping(
        value = "/test", 
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> post(@ModelAttribute FormBean request){
        // request.getParam() == null   
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

```java
public class FormBean {

    private String param1;

    public String getParam1() {
        return param1;
    }

    public void setParam1(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/test" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="param1">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `name` attribute in your HTML inputs, `id` attribute is meaningless when posting an HTML form

```
<input type="text" name="param1">
```

Comment: Adding name attributes allows my data to reach the bean. Also, not need EnableWebMvc either.