# Spring boot + Thymeleaf + ajax cannot send VO or DTO Controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to send form data through thymeleaf + ajax to Java Controller.
But at ReplyDto, can't receive data.

This is my code.

Themeleaf, Ajax .html

```
function insertReply() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/reply/insertReply',
        data: $("#replyForm").serialize(),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("test");
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert("Error : " + error + "\nStatus : " + status + "\nRequest : " + request);
        }
    });
}

    <form id="replyForm" th:object="${replyDto}" th:method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="${post.postNo}" th:value="${post.postNo}">
        
        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{replyTitle}" placeholder="replyTitle">
        <textarea class="form-control" th:field="*{replyContent}" placeholder="insert" id="replyContentData" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="replyInsertButton" type="button" onclick='insertReply()'>댓글 입력</button>
    </form>
```

ReplyDto.java

```
private int replyNo;
private String replyTitle;
private String replyContent;
private int postNo;
```

ReplyContoller.java

```
@PostMapping("/insertReply")
public int insertReply(ReplyDto replyDto) {
    System.out.println(replyDto.getPostNo());
    System.out.println(replyDto.getReplyTitle());
    System.out.println(replyDto.getReplyContent());
    return replyService.insertReply(replyDto);
}
```

Controller has annotation @RestController.
At console, log 0, null, null each postNo, replyTitle, replyContent.

How can I get form data to Controller?
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your are missing `@RequestBody`

   public int insertReply(@RequestBody ReplyDto replyDto) { ...
2. `$("#replyForm").serialize()` turns form into query string. You need valid JSON

You should probably go for a solution like this: [Spring RestController POST accepting a basic HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58036104/spring-restcontroller-post-accepting-a-basic-html-form)

If you insist on proceeding with your current solution:

Start with verifying controller in Postman when fixed missing `@RequestBody`.

Converting form to JSON:

- https://www.learnwithjason.dev/blog/get-form-values-as-json/
- https://medium.com/@mwakatumbula_/code-15ecdb18c2ef
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/

Comment: Thank you. I solved using @RequestBody. And changed serialize data to JSON.stringfy($("#replyForm").serialize()). But created another error.

Comment: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: I used form-method: post, ajax type: post, receive @PostMapping at Controller.